# Is there a solution for the following: I am getting the error in my vbscript: "Microsoft Excel: Autofilter Method of Range class failed"

Tags: excel, vba

I have gone through may threads. Still, I am getting the error. The data is valid. Please help.

```
'Option Explicit
'create the excel object
Dim objExcel
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 

'view the excel program and file, set to false to hide the whole process
objExcel.Visible = True 

'open an excel file (make sure to change the location) .xls for 2003 or earlier
Dim objWorkbook
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\PParkhe\Desktop\Jan-19 BT IOP1.xlsx")
Const xlUp = -4162
DeleteRowsWithAutofilter

Public Sub DeleteRowsWithAutofilter()

    Dim wksData' As Worksheet
    Dim lngLastRow 'As Long
    Dim rngData 'As Range

    'Set references up-front
    Set wksData = objExcel.Worksheets("DATA")
    wksdata.AutoFilterMode = False

    'Identify the last row and use that info to set up the Range
    With wksData
        lngLastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rngData = .Range("A1:C9" & lngLastRow)
    End With

    'Here is where we use the .AutoFilter method to crush those
    'annoying "Thumbs.db" and "Invoice.zip" rows
    'Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        With rngData

            'Apply the Autofilter method to the first column of
            'the range, using xlOr to select either
            '"Thumbs.db" or "Invoice.zip"
            .AutoFilter Field = 1, _
                        Criteria1="=2"', _
                        'Operator:=xlOr, _
                        'Criteria2:="Invoice.zip"

            'Delete the visible rows while keeping the header
            .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Delete
        End With
    'Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    'Turn off the AutoFilter
    With wksData
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        If .FilterMode = True Then
            .ShowAllData
        End If
    End With

    'Let the user know the rows have been removed
    MsgBox "Damn son! Rows removed."

End Sub

objExcel.DisplayAlerts = True
objExcel.ScreenUpdating = True

'save the existing excel file. use SaveAs to save it as something else
objWorkbook.Save

'close the workbook
objWorkbook.Close 

'exit the excel program
objExcel.Quit

'release objects
Set objExcel = Nothing
Set objWorkbook = Nothing



'Sub displayMessage()
'  MsgBox "hello world!"
'End Sub
```

The script is not going to autofilter itself.

Comment: `Set rngData = .Range("A1:C9" & lngLastRow)` is that `9` a typo?

Comment: Is that code within another procedure?  You can't `Set` objects outside a procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `:`

Change

```
Field = 1,Criteria1="=2"
```

to

```
Field:=1, Criteria1:="=2"
```

Also declare `Const xlCellTypeVisible = 12` at the top like you did for `xlUp`